# Why does `shape aspect` not work for rectangular TikZ nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-shape

The documentation of TikZ seems to indicate that `shape aspect` is available for all node shapes. However, the command is only available if `shapes.geometric` is loaded and for some shapes (e.g. diamond). I tried to apply it to a rectangle, but without success:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcommand\ww{4cm}
  \node[draw, minimum width=\ww,shape aspect=5] {};
  %  works
  \node[draw, diamond, minimum width=\ww,shape aspect=5, yshift=-1cm] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Did I miss something? How can I construct rectangles with `minimum width` and a ratio? Do I have to use the painful `\pgfmathresult` macros to calculate it manually (I dislike them).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is none but you can cook up yourself. Here is my two-minute mock-up without much thinking because I'm watching something else with my other eye

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  adjust height/.style={minimum height=#1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}},
  adjust width/.style={minimum width=#1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum height}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[fill=blue!40,minimum width=2cm,adjust height=3] (a) at (0,0) {Lawrence Tierney};
\node[fill=orange!50!black,minimum height=2cm,adjust width=3] (a) at (5,0) {Tim Roth};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This method is nice, I've come across the `\pgfkeysvalueof` macro. I'll accept this answer soon, but I want to be the one pushing you above 100k rep (perhaps happening today).